# How to test d3.js with mocha?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mocha.js

I have a script which call d3.js and then try to read a csv :

```
var d3      = require ("./../../librairies/d3.v2.js")
d3.csv  (   path_to_read, function(data , error)
```

When I run a test on it with mocha, d3 can not do any XML request :

```
 ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined
      at d3_xhr (d3.v2.js:1936:114)
```

How can I include and test d3 with mocha (I am quite new with Mocha) ?

Comment: You might find this [blog post](http://jsdatav.is/visuals.html?id=dcb31c1de5940d2fca9c) helpful

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is that some objects are not available in Node.js because Node.js is not a web browser. One of those objects is the `XMLHttpRequest` object. You could find a library that would make this object available in Node.js but I would not recommend you to do that.

Your second problem is that D3 sometimes leads to hard to test code.

To avoid this you need to write your D3 code in a way that makes it easy to test. So instead of:

```
d3.csv(path_to_read, function(data, error) {
   // all your code goes here
})
```

You need something like:

```
// some pure functions (data in d3 elements out)
function renderAxis(data) {
    return {};
}

function renderData(data) {
    return {};
}

function renderSomethingElse(data) {
    return {};
}

// one pure function that uses all the other pure functions
// returns a function that needs to be invoked when data finishes loading
function renderEverything(renderAxisFunc, renderDataFunc, renderSomethingElseFunc) {
   return onDataLoaded(data, error) {
      var axis = renderAxisFunc(data);
      var dataPoints = renderAxisFunc(data);
      var somethingElse = renderSomethingElseFunc(data);
      return {
          axis: axis,
          dataPoints: dataPoints,
          somethingElse: somethingElse
      };
   }
}

// Finally you can use the pure functions
d3.csv(path_to_read, function(data, error) {
   var dataLoaded = renderEverything(renderAxis, renderData, renderSomethingElse)
   var chartElements = dataLoaded(data, error);
   // append chartElements
})
```

If you write have pure functions testing become trivial:

```
expect(renderAxis([{/* some mock data */}])).to.eq(/* expected d3 objects*/);
expect(renderData([{/* some mock data */}])).to.eq(/* expected d3 objects*/);
expect(renderSomethingElse([{/* some mock data */}])).to.eq(/* expected d3 objects*/);
```

You can also test the big one:

```
var dataLoaded = renderEverything(
    (data) => { /* mock response */ },
    (data) => { /* mock response */ },
    (data) => { /* mock response */ }
);

expect(data([{/* some mock data */}], false)).to.eq(/* expected d3 objects*/);
```